# Get integer row index of MultiIndex Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas Series with a MultiIndex, and I want to get the integer row numbers that belong to one level of the MultiIndex.

For example, if I have sample data `s`

```
s = pandas.Series([10, 23, 2, 19], 
                  index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]))
```

which looks like this:

```
a c    10
  d    23
b c    2
  d    19
```

I want to get the row numbers that correspond to the level `b`. So here, I'd get `[2, 3]` as the output, because the last two rows are under `b`. Also, I really only need the first row that belongs under `b`.

I wanted to get the numbers so that I can compare across Series. Say I have five Series objects with a `b` level. These are time-series data, and `b` corresponds to a condition that was present during some of the observations (and `c` is a sub-condition, etc). I want to see which Series had the conditions present at the same time.

Edit: To clarify, I don't need to compare the values themselves, just the indices. For example, in R if I had this dataframe:

```
d = data.frame(col_1 = c('a','a','b','b'), col_2 = c('c','d','c','d'), col_3 = runif(4))
```

Then the command `which(d$col_1 == 'b')` would produce the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

If the index that you want to index by is the outermost one you can use `loc`

```
df.loc['b']
```

To get the first row I find the `head` method the easiest

```
df.loc['b'].head(1)
```

The idiomatic way to do the second part of your question is as follows. Say your series are named series1, series2 and series3.

```
big_series = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3])
big_series.loc['b']
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually needed the integer index number in the original series. So `s.loc['b'].head(1)` will return the contents, but I need it to return where in `s` those contents are located.

Comment: If it is just to compare the locatoins in each series you should place all your series in a list, and then concat them. You can get all the values in one go by using `loc`